# How to get all logged-in google users

Tags: google-people-api

I am trying to get all Gmail logged in the user list. Have tried almost everything from Google API, but got no success.
If someone can provide a solution.

url = "https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: That would be a very, very big list. I think you have to work for Google to get that.

Comment: I am not asking about whole google, just asking the over a particular browser.